# Downvote Area 51 proposals

Tags: feature-request, area-51

So far it seems that you can aid an Area51 proposal by following it or whatever. I wish to express the entirely reverse sentiment by effectively "downvoting" it.

Comment: I wanna down vote people. *individuals*. In real life. Please call your favorite politician if you support this idea.

Comment: @Shog9 but the politicians themselves are typically the people I want to downvote in the first place...

Comment: We should distract them with some swag

Answer (score 4):

If you think a proposal is bad, you could post your criticism in the Area 51 Discussions site. If you click the "create new discussion" link on a proposal, a link to the proposal will be automatically included.
This is more constructive than a "downvote" on a proposal. More than a few proposals have been discarded after a discussion.

It is true that our regular Q&A sites are more democratic - our votes influence posts there directly, whereas on Area 51 it is Stack Overflow (the company) that decides which proposals will live.

I'm guessing this system is deliberate; Stack Overflow wants to encourage people to create new sites, and downvotes on a proposal would discourage people. But don't think you're powerless in the face of bad proposals; write a well-considered criticism and a bad proposal will be taken down.

Comment: I could do those things, but I prefer to be able to downvote anonymously, just like I can normally.

Comment: @DeadMG I know the feeling... with luck, though, someone else will write a criticism, and you can anonymously upvote that.

Comment: Skipping those unnecessary intermediate steps is the entire purpose of the feature request.

Answer (score 3):

While the feature request makes sense, with the followers alone, Area 51 proposal can't move to the next phase, i.e. commitment. Forty questions with the score of ten or more are also required. Taking this into account, I simply down vote the questions when I don't like the proposal (you can also vote to close - the closed questions don't count towards the progress of the proposal).